# Instantiating parameters of onCreateView(...)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

hi i'm new in android programming and i will appreciate any answer that can help me understand this concept. Thanks in advance.

so i'm studying a book about android programming and i'm on the page instructing me to override the `onCreateView(...)` method and it goes like this...

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime,container,false);
    return v;
}
```

What i dont understand is that we dont instantiated the parameter "LayoutInflater" but still on the method statement we use an object "inflater"to call inflate method.same with next parameter we just use the name "container"but i dont know if we instantiate that. how come we can use inflate when we didnt yet instantiate it? or if we instantiated that,when? .

i apologize if someone find it irrelevant question. i just want to understand the concept or its rule. thank you

Answer (score 0):

We never instantiate an abstract class. In your case, both LayoutInflater and ViewGroup are abstract classes. The concept of abstract class in android in same as in Java. "The abstract classes can have static methods or fields also". Therefore, the inflate method is called without an object being created of its base class which is LayoutInflater and that is abstract in nature.

The Context.getSystemService() will scan all the layout folders/files on the project at the application level. You can then inflate any of the layouts as per your need. Hope this helps :)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup

Comment: i will look into that. Thanks for ur answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime,container,false);
TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewByid(R.id.text)